# Sench Touch List is not rendering the data

Tags: sencha-touch-2.2

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Facility', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax'
    ],

    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'FacilityId'
            },
            {
                name: 'FacilityName'
            }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.store.FacilityStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.Facility'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'MyApp.model.Facility',
        storeId: 'FacilityStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            batchActions: false,
            url: 'http://localhost/QuickFind/Services/EquipmentService.asmx/GetFacilities',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'd'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And trying the load the data into the list.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.facilityList', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    alias: 'widget.facilityList',

    config: {
        docked: 'top',
        height: 200,
        id: 'datalist',
        ui: 'round',
        scrollable: true,
        store: 'FacilityStore',
        onItemDisclosure: true,
        itemTpl: [
            '<div><p>{Facility.FacilityName}</p></div>'
        ]
    }

});
```

and my controller launch i am binding the data to the list:

> Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Facility', {
>       extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
>
> ```
> config: {
>     refs: {
>         dataList: '#dataList',
>         mainNav: 'mainNav'
>     }
> },
>
> launch: function() {
>
>     var me = this;
>
>     debugger;
>
>     Ext.getStore('FacilityStore').load();
>     var group_store = Ext.getStore("FacilityStore");
>
>     me.facilityList.setStore(group_store);
>
> }
> ```

Store is loaded with records but it's not displaying in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I hope u have solved ur problem by this moment,but still to answer the question u have posted..the problem is the itemtpl u have written..

ur's

```
itemTpl: [
            '<div><p>{Facility.FacilityName}</p></div>'
        ]
```

The field u have mentioned is `FacilityName` so to get the record's from the store `Facility`

U just need to do this in ur itemtpl to get data in list:

```
itemTpl: [
                '<div><p>{FacilityName}</p></div>'
            ]
```